# Painting between curves

Tags: pstricks, pscustom

I have a file with the points of a gaussian. I'm trying to paint the half of it (dividing it vertically). I'm using \pscustom but it keep painting the whole gaussian. What do you think the problem is?

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[crop=true]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-func,animate}
\pagestyle{empty}

\readdata{\dataGauss}{dataGauss.txt}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(16,7.6)

\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]{
\listplot[linewidth=0.04, linecolor=blue]{\dataGauss}
\psplot[linewidth=0pt,plotpoints=500,linecolor=black] {3.5}{7.5}{ 0 }}


\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post the data file so we can play with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're required to use pstricks, but if not may I suggest taking a look at `tikz-pgf`. For example (I'm using a made-up data set, not yours):

```
\documentclass[border = 0.2in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-2, -0.2) rectangle (0, 1.2);
    \path [fill = lightgray]
      plot [mark = x, smooth] file {gauss.table};
  \end{scope}
  \draw [thick]
    plot [mark = x, smooth] file {gauss.table};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Like Derek's answer using tikz, but without using tables or scope.

```
\documentclass[border = 0.2in]{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    \fill [LightGray,domain=-2:0,samples=200]  plot (\x,{exp(-2*\x*\x)}) -- (0,0) -- (-2,0) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick,domain=-2:2,samples=200] plot (\x,{exp(-2*\x*\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I would do, but I wasn't sure if the OP had true gaussian data, or some sort of approximation.

Answer (score 3):

`pst-func` has a function `\psGauss`. Here is a solution with some given values:

```
\documentclass[crop=true,pstricks]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dataGauss.txt}
-4   0
-3.5 0.005
-3   0.01
-2.5 0.02
-2  0.05
-1.5 0.14
-1   0.245
-0.5 0.35
0   0.4
0.5 0.35
1  0.245
1.5 0.14
2 0.05
2.5 0.02
3 0.01
4 0
}
\end{filecontents*}

\readdata{\dataGauss}{dataGauss.txt}

\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=5}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-0.1)(5,0.5)
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!40,linestyle=none]{%
  \listplot[xEnd=0,plotstyle=curve]{\dataGauss}
  \psline(0,0)(-2.9,0)}
\listplot[xStart=0,linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed,plotstyle=curve]{\dataGauss}
\listplot[xEnd=0,linecolor=blue,plotstyle=curve]{\dataGauss}
\psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-4.5,0)(4.5,0.45)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]